# I'm getting NoSuchWindowException @ clicking OK button in popup (popup closes afterwards)

Tags: java, selenium

I'm getting `Method threw 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.toString()` after clicking the OK button in a popup in the debug mode.

```
This is causing the next error in the console:
[1562769428.065][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
[1562769428.065][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

The strange thing is that the code continues to execute.
After clicking ok it changes to mainwindow and executes the rest of the code succesfully. Please help me to get rid of this error?

```
   public void clickBelangrijkeNotitie() {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(Constant.BELANGRIJKE_NOTITIE_ACTIVITY_CSS_LOCATOR_VALUE)));
       HandleNewWindow.setMainWindow(driver);
       elements.belangrijkeNotitie.click();
       HandleNewWindow.switchToNewWindow(driver, wait);
       System.out.println("switching to new window");
   }

public void typeNotitie(String notitie) {
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(Constant.NOTITIE_INPUT_FIELD_ID_LOCATOR_VALUE)));
       elements.notitie.clear();
       elements.notitie.sendKeys(notitie);
   }

   public void clickOkButton() {
       elements.okButton.click();
       HandleNewWindow.switchToMainWindow(driver);
   }

   public class HandleNewWindow {
    protected static String mainWindow;
    public static void setMainWindow(WebDriver driver) {
        mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    }

    public static void switchToNewWindow(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
        Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String newWindow : allWindows) {
            if (!newWindow.equals(mainWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void switchToMainWindow(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
    }
}
     @Test (testName = "Create belangrijke and standaard notitie")
    public void testBelangrijkeEnStandaardNotitie() {
            logIn.logInToPowerCurveWithUserX(npa.USERNAME, npa.PASSWORD);
            search.searchAccount(accountNummer3);
            activities.clickNotitieParentActivity();
            activities.clickBelangrijkeNotitie();
            popUpActivities.typeNotitie("Een belangrijke notitie: Dit is een effectieve test....");
            popUpActivities.clickOkButton();
            activities.clickNotitieParentActivity();
            activities.clickStandaardNotitie();
            popUpActivities.typeNotitie("Standaard notitie ook maar even doen.......");
            popUpActivities.clickOkButton();
            toolbarActivities.clickAccountOntladenButton();
            logOut.logOutFromPowerCurve();
    }
}
```

so this is causing the exception:
elements.okButton.click();

Comment: could you be calling "setMainWindow" before switching back?  You may want to set that once... and not make it static.

Comment: no not really, the weird thing is that i also build assertions now, and they all work as expected......